# Date format and data extract from Pentaho Kettle Spoon

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using Kettle Spoon for transformation.

1. How do I give fixed input date from 'Get System Info'? I see options of selecting yesterday, month ago etc. But I want to select fixed date manually such as: '2012-12-14'
2. I got an csv, 'text file output' from transformation. The outputs are for say A, B, C, D, E. I want to filter and get only A, B, D, E.
   How do I filter from 'text file output' and select only desired columns to get my data into final table.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1) use a select value step right after the "Get system info". In the Meta-data tab choose the field, use type Date and choose the desired format mask (yyyy-MM-dd).

2) if you need filtering columns, i.e. dropping some columns from output, again use select value step; if you need filtering rows based on the values contained in a field/column, then use filter rows step.

Comment: Thanks for the response. On 'get system info' what value do I select for 'type' field? On 'select values' step, on 'metadata' tab what do I need to do so I can have manual dates like '2012-12-3', '2012-12-4' etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to add hard coded dates, rather than reformat existing dates. If that's the case, just use an Add Constants step. Set the column type to Date. If you need to do it as a source step you can use a Data Grid or Generate Rows step.

If you want to remove columns from a text file output, you can use a Select Values step as @andtorg said, but you can also simply remove the columns from the Fields tab of the Text File Output step.

Answer (score 0):

Use Modified Javascript Value 
Add Modified Javascript Value  in PDI and Choose whatever format u want .